# Quantum computation implications of (P vs NP)

Tags: computational-complexity, computability-theory, quantum-mechanics, np

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What impact would P!=NP  have on the characterization of BQP?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35151/what-impact-would-pnp-have-on-the-characterization-of-bqp)

Before I begin, I had a similar post closed for mentioning the recently released (to be verified) proof that P!=NP. This question is about the implications of P!=NP, not about the proof internals or specifics.

Does P!=NP imply that NP-Complete problems cannot be solved in Quantum Polynomial time?

According to Wikipedia, quantum complexity classes BQP and QMA which are the bounded-error quantum analogues of P and NP. If P!=NP was a know fact, does that imply that BQP!=QMA?

Comment: Is now really the best time for someone who does not usually care about it to ask these questions ?

Comment: I'm closing as duplicate. It looks like the other question may reopen anyway...

Comment: I started studying quantum mechanics and algorithms recently and, yes, the recent news sparked the question. I do care about what I am studying and the potential evolutions of the field.

Comment: The other question is now reopen.

Comment: @David Lehavi: Yes! When a big proof in computational complexity is announced, of course people are going to wonder how it will effect other big open problems. When Poincare came out, I was definitely asking my friends whether this gave a new algorithm for knot isomorphism. In this case, the question is at the right level for MO, so why not ask it here? (Of course, I don't know that unknown (yahoo) doesn't think about these issues all the time, but I am willing to tentatively assume he or she does not.)


Comment: The answers to both your questions are simply “no”: P≠NP is not known to imply BQP⊉NP or BQP≠QMA.